# What is the ruby equivalent of python -i?

Tags: python, ruby

`python -i` will execute a script then provide an interactive prompt which still has access to the variables declared in the script. Does ruby have an equivalent option? I've tried `require` but it seems the variables are no longer in scope after using it. E.g.,:

```
Steven$ cat simple.rb 
s = "hello"

Steven$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require_relative('simple')
=> true
irb(main):002:0> puts s
NameError: undefined local variable or method `s' for main:Object
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0>
```

Comment: Well, `s` is a *local variable*. Local variables are called local variables because they are local to the scope they are defined in. In this case, `s`'s scope is the script body of `simple.rb`. It can be accessed there and only there. If you want a variable with a different scope, you need to use a differently scoped variable, in this case probably either a global variable or an instance variable of `main`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry):

`simple.rb`:

```
s = "hello"
binding.pry
```

in the console:

```
$ pry simple.rb 
[1] pry(main)> puts s
hello
=> nil
[2] pry(main)>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, you access environment variables with the ENV hash with the variable name as the key. For example,

```
[max@max:~] $ export PIE=pecan
[max@max:~] $ irb
1.9.3-p385 :001 > print ENV['PIE']
pecan => nil
```

Comment: This question isn't about environment variables.